# Setting up RESTFull web app project using Maven Eclipse and Tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, jersey

So I have been trying to create a new RESTfull web application project in eclipse that will use the Jersey Jax-rs framework and work on a tomcat server. So far i have been able to create the project in eclipse and add the jersey dependencies , but I am missing files like web.xml so I am unsure weather I am doing this properly.

Would somebody with experience in this field that perhaps does this often give me a step by step walkthrough of the steps involved to see what I am missing as im sure its not complicated im just brand new to this so its all confusing .

I want to use jersey and the jersey test framework.

Thanks in advance 
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the tutorial I used - and this is quite simple.

http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/02/rest-jersey-configuration-on-tomcat.html

and let us know if anything is not working.

When you create a **"Dynamic Web Project"** in "Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers" , it will make a basic web.xml for you - so just add the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` tags as needed

Comment: How would this work with a maven build would i create the maven project structure then import that into the dynamic web project?

Comment: no worrys got it eclipse maven plugin has a helpfull web app setting

Comment: dude i guess question is "making RESTful web app using maven" and in your answer where is "maven" ?